# php dropdown is displaying correct number of table contents, just no name for them

Tags: php, oracle

```
<?php
$conn = oracle credentials;
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT location_name 
                          FROM ARTISTLOCATION');
            //prepare
        if (!$stid) {
            $e = oci_error($conn);
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        // logic
        $r = oci_execute($stid);
        if (!$r) {
            $e = oci_error($stid);
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES),  E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        // fetch
        echo '<label> Select Artist Location:</label>';
        echo '<select>';
        //echo '<option value="">Select a location</option>';

        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['location_id']."'>".$row['location_name'].'</option>';

        }

        echo '</select>';
        oci_free_statement($stid);       
?>
```

It shows a dropdown and the correct amount of options, they're just blank. I've been staring at it too long and I can't figure it out.

Comment: inside the loop `var_dump($row);`

Comment: oracle is stingy about capitals.. try `$row['LOCATION_ID']`

Comment: Oh my. You're a life saver pamblam. How dumb of me.

Comment: a little debugging goes a long way, had you followed my congestion you would of seen your variables where wrong